# i am trying to use pako 2.1.0 library , it is not supporting for string inputs , so i tried with uint8Array . still having problem

Tags: node.js, compression, node-modules, gzip, pako

```
data= {
    "AgreementId": "131",
    "Type": "Admin",
    "validFrom": "2020-07-12",
    "validTo": "2021-08-10",
    "internalDescription": "InternalDescrip",
    "customerName": "Test Customer",
}
```

first  step we are converting data to uint8Array then we compressing the data and encding it to base64

```
const uint8Array = new TextEncoder().encode(JSON.stringify(data)) 
const compressedData = gzip(uint8Array) 
const base64EncodedData = base64Encode(compressedData)
```

```
  const strData = base64Decode(base64EncodedData);
          const charData = strData.split('').map(function(x){return x.charCodeAt(0); });
          console.log(charData,"CHARDATA")
          const binData = new Uint8Array(charData);
          console.log(binData,"BINDATA")
          const result = ungzip(binData, { to: 'string' }, { raw: true });
          console.log(result,"RESULT");
```

Then i tried to decompress and decode the array and it s not giving the result . ungzip method is not working .
**Error: incorrect header check**

Comment: You specified `raw` when decompressing with `ungzip()`, but not when compressing with `gzip()`. Get rid of the `raw`.

Comment: @MarkAdler It didnt work when i tried with out adding the raw attribute .